# Click event on canvas with background

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, mouseevent

I have UserControl, which contains Canvas (in Grid).
When I just clicked on canvas event PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown or MouseLeftButtonDown works perfectly, but when I set `canvas.Background = new ImageBrush(imgs);` and try to click on canvas, events doesn't raising. I tried to make same events for grid (canvas parent), but result was the same.

UPD1: canvas has children - rectangle (from System.Windows.Shapes) around cursor, maybe it somehow affect on events.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As is [customary on this website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), please show us the code that you have used in order to help us fully understand your problem and find a solution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In wpf there are two possible scenarios where hit testing (clicking with mouse somewhere) is not working. These two are ment to be that way and it is by design. I am talking about when your Background is NULL or when you have the property IsHitTestVisible set to false.

In any other case hit testing/clicking will work.

I assume your background is null somehow. Maybe imgs throws error which will be catched in an empty try/catch block internally at render time.

Tell us is the background property of your canvas null?

There is a nice tool called Snoop which allows you to snoop an wpf app and change properties at runtime. Use that tool to change the background and tell us about the results.

**EDIT:**

First of all the default value of Canvas Background is null therefore by default you can click as often you wish on Canvas and nothing will happen.

As soon you change the Background to Yellow it clicking will work and your handler will be called.

Comment: IsHitTestVisible set to "true"
When I starting progran, canvas background is null and events about mouse click are raisin, but when I set some image as background and starting to draw rectangle around cursor events doesn't raising anymore.
About Snoop: yes, I know about it, but when I choose my application and push "Snoop" button nothing happens.

Comment: I edited my answer. By default Canvas is not throwing around with any click events or MouseLeftButtonDown events

Comment: Thanks, I accidantaly edited wrong post and sorry about it. I found a decision: I just added to the rectangle object event MouseLeftButtonDown like this: `r.MouseLeftButtonDown += MouseLeftButtonDown;` and now all works.